# Calculate probability that X > Y, given that also Z > Y

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be i.i.d. and all $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

It can easily be shown that $A = (X-Y) = \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$, and thus $\mathbb{P}(X>Y) = 1/2$

But supposing it is already known that $Z > Y$. My instinct is that this changes the distribution of $Y$? In some sense, $Z$ is "probably a bit higher than average" and $Y$ is "probably a bit lower than average".

Thus I would expect that the distribution of $B = (Y_{Z>Y})$ is no longer $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

What, then, *is* it's distribution, and how would I calculate the conditional probability: $\mathbb{P}((X>Y)_{Z>Y})$

Comment: Hint:  there are $3!=6$ equally probable ways to order samples of the three variables $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: @lulu are you suggesting that the probability is simply 2/3?

Comment: Exactly.  $\quad$

Comment: That does fit my broad intuition of "it means $Y$ was lower than average".

Comment: Is determining the distribution of $B$ at all do-able?

Comment: I expect it can be worked out...though I can't recall if it has some especially simple form or not.  I suggest working it out for i.i.d uniform variables first.

Comment: Please use the standard notation $P(X > Y | Z > Y)$ to denote conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, 
\begin{align}
P(X > Y | Z > Y) = P(X > Y, Z > Y) / P(Z > Y) = 2P(X > Y, Z > Y).
\end{align}

To calculate $P(X > Y, Z > Y)$, using independence between $X, Z$ and $Y$, we have:
\begin{align}
   & P(X > Y, Z > Y) \\
= & \int_{\mathbb{R}}P(X > y, Z > y)\varphi(y)dy \\
= & \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1 - \Phi(y))^2\varphi(y) dy \\
= & \int_0^1 (1 - t)^2dt = \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

Therefore the answer is $2/3$.